# mysql export to csv with related fields concated

Tags: mysql, export-to-csv

I need to export my mysql db to a csv file. Where I'm going to be using it can't have related tables, so I need to concat related records into a single field. Is this possible to do? For example, assuming this table structure:

```
Items: id as INT, name as VARCHAR
ItemIdentifiers: id as INT, item_id as INT, identifier_id as INT
Identifiers: id as INT, identifier as VARCHAR
ItemColors: id as INT, item_id as INT, color_id as INT
Colors: id as INT, color as VARCHAR
```

and assuming this data:

```
Items: (1, 'some name')
ItemIdentifiers: (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2)
Identifiers: (1, 'ident1'), (2, 'ident2')
ItemColors: (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2)
Colors: (1, 'blue'), (2, 'green')
```

How would I get this:

> 'some name', 'ident1 ident2', 'blue green'

That's just a basic example, but I hope that conveys what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Why not having 2 rows: one for `ident1` and the other for `ident2`?

Comment: because that would create extreme amounts of unnecessary duplicating. I could end up having 20 records for just 1 item.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function in combination with [SELECT ... INTO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       items.name AS `Name`, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT identifiers.identifier 
               ORDER BY identifiers.identifier 
               SEPARATOR ' ') AS `Identifiers`, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT colors.color 
               ORDER BY colors.color 
               SEPARATOR ' ') AS `colors` 
       INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/data.csv'
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
       LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM   items 
       JOIN itemidentifiers 
         ON ( itemidentifiers.item_id = items.id ) 
       JOIN identifiers 
         ON ( itemidentifiers.identifiers_id = identifiers.id ) 
       JOIN itemcolors 
         ON ( itemcolors.item_id = items.id ) 
       JOIN colors 
         ON ( colors.id = itemcolors.color_id ) 
GROUP BY Items.id
```

You might notice there are too many `JOIN`s. This is because you have used relational tables. For each relational tables there are 1 additional `JOIN`

**Note:** The above query is experimental. I haven't tested it yet.